How to lift the fundamental theorem of algebra proof from topology into algebra?
There exist some proof of fundamental theorem of algebra using only topological properties of $\mathbb{C}$ eg, but as far as I understand these theorems prove fundamental theorem of algebra for polynomial functions rather than formal polynomial expressions.
My question is if one does prove the fundamnetal theorem of algebra for polynomial functions how does one lift this into a fundamental theorem of algebra for elements in the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$? I think this is non obvious in how one does this because polynomial functions and polynomials as elements of polynomial ring are conceptually different. This conceptual difference also plays a rule in how you prove things about them. For example, it's kinda hard to prove if a polynomial is equal to zero then it's coefficients are zero for polynomial functions but easy for elements in the polynomial ring as it comes out of construction.

Please do not answer in the comments.

If $K$ is an infinite field, then the ring of formal polynomials over $K$ and the ring of polynomial functions over $K$ are isomorphic, because if two formal polynomials $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_mx^m$ and $g(x) = b_0 + b_1x + \ldots + b_nx^n$ satisfy $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in K$, then $f(x) - g(x)$ is a polynomial function with infinitely many roots, which is impossible unless $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are identical as formal polynomials.
If $K$ is finite, then two distinct formal polynomials can give the same polynomial function on $K$. E.g., if $K = \Bbb{Z}_2$, the formal polynomials $x$ and $x^3$ give the same polynomial function on $K$ but are not equal in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$.
